# What are the argument formats accepted for fopen()

Tags: c, posix, fopen

Are there all types of files that can be opened with notepad like .txt, .c or .java the same ones that can be opened with `fopen()` or is there any exception?

Comment: Your question is about Notepad application or C programming ?

Comment: You may have misunderstood how c models files. C doesn't know anything about "formats" every file is a ordered bag of bytes. Doing something intelligent with that bag is *your* problem. Or someone else's if you're clever enough to use a third part library to help you out...

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with the question itself (and how is the latter related to programming)?

Comment: You can open any file using `fopen()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that C does not care about file types and therefore your assumption is true.

The long answer is that the short answer only applies to regular files (all of the ones listed by you are regular files), in some cases it does not apply to special files like device files, FIFOs. On Windows, you might have an issue with links (`.lnk` files), depending on your C library. The C library might not follow those links whereas Notepad will.

That does however not mean that the file in question will be displayed correctly. Encoding and/or linebreaks might be an issue.

Comment: Ok, for instance, i have a program that counts the number of words if the entered file [fopen(argv[1], "r")]. With those files that can be opened with notepad, i get the counting right. But with files that are not expected to have an answer distinct from 0 (for instance, a .docx file) i get a number (which of course is different from the real number in the file). How does C obtain the numbers with for instance .docx files, how does it fopen a docx?

Comment: @AdrianGilOrs: C doesn't count words for you unless you tell C how to do this.

Comment: @AdrianGilOrs By using `fopen()` and related, you would just get the binary DOCX data. C does not know, in any case, how to interpret that data (that's your job as a programmer!)